# Remove DatePicker border (macOS / SwiftUI)

Tags: macos, swiftui, datepicker

I'm trying to style by DatePicker() field a bit to make it look better than the poor built-in styling.

Here's what I have so far, which mostly works:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
    Text("Update Date")
        .font(.body)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                
    DatePicker("", selection: $caseUpdates[index].updateDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        .datePickerStyle(.automatic)
        .frame(width: 120, alignment: .leading)
        .frame(height: 32)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)) // Set custom border
}
```

Here's what I end up with:
[image]

As you can see, the date field still has the (ugly) built-in border, which I have no idea how to remove.

I tried using `.background(Color.clear)` and                                  `.border(Color.clear)` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: After some investigation, I still found no way to do that with SwiftUI alone. Had to use AppKit to achieve this.

Comment: can you share the code for how you did it in AppKit

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if this topic is still relevant. Afaik, there's no built in solution for styling date fields.
I help myself, using a simple TextField for adding Dates. I made an own view for that.

```
struct DatePickerView: View {
    
    let label: String
    @Binding var date: Date
    let labelWidth: Double
    let spacer: Bool
    
    init(
        label: String,
        date: Binding<Date>,
        labelWidth: Double = AppSettings.labelWidth,
        spacer: Bool = true
    ) {
        self.label = label
        _date = date
        self.labelWidth = labelWidth
        self.spacer = spacer
    }
    
    @State private var showPopoverDate: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 0) {
            Label(label, systemImage: "apple.logo")
                .labelStyle(.titleOnly)
                .frame(width: labelWidth, alignment: .leading)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
//              .font(.callout)
            if spacer {
                Spacer()
            }
            TextField(label, value: $date, formatter: Formatters.dateFormatter, prompt: Text(Formatters.dateFormatter.string(from: Date.now)))
                .frame(width: 100)
                .labelsHidden()
            Button {
                showPopoverDate.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
            .padding(.leading, 9)
            .popover(isPresented: $showPopoverDate, arrowEdge: .trailing) {
                DatePicker(selection: Binding<Date>(
                    get: {self.date},
                    set: {self.date = $0}
                ), displayedComponents: [.date], label: { Text("gebDat") })
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                .accentColor(.accentColor)
                .padding(10)
                .font(.body)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: AppSettings.fieldHeight)
        .padding(AppSettings.fieldPadding)
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.